# Every possible difference among multiple vectors

Tags: matlab

I have 3 vectors, v1, v2, v3. What I want to get is the difference between every possible pair of them, that is, v1-v2, v1-v3, v2-v3. How can I do this without looping in matlab?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have combvec in my matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Concatenate all vectors to form a 2D array
V = cat(2,v1(:),v2(:),v3(:),v4(:),v5(:))

N = size(V,2) %// number of vectors

%// Find all IDs of all combinations as x,y
[y,x] = find(bsxfun(@gt,[1:N]',[1:N])) %//'
%// OR [y,x] = find(tril(true(size(V,2)),-1))

%// Use matrix indxeing to collect vector data for all combinations with those 
%// x-y IDs from V. Then, perform subtractions across them for final output
diff_array = V(:,x) - V(:,y)
```

**Few points about the code**

1. **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** with `find` gets us the IDs for forming pairwise combinations.
2. We use those IDs to index into the 2D concatenated array and perform subtractions between them to get the final output.

---

**Bonus Stuff**

If you look closely into the part where it finds the `IDs` of all combinations, that is basically `nchoosek(1:..,2)`.

So, basically one can have alternatives to `nchoosek(1:N,2)` as:

1. `[Y,X] = find(bsxfun(@gt,[1:N]',[1:N]))`
2. `[y,x] = find(tril(true(N),-1))`

with `[X Y]` forming those pairwise combinations and might be interesting to benchmark them!

Comment: @meng Please start accepting solutions for this question and your previous question! For accepting a particular solution, you need to click on the hollow checkmark next to the solution, so that hollow checkmark turns into green checkmark!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `nchoosek` to generate the combinations first and then use them to index into your array of row-vectors:

Test case:

```
numVectors = 3;
dim = 5;
Vs = rand(numVectors, dim);
```

Actual computation:

```
combs = nchoosek(1:size(Vs,1), 2);
differences = Vs(combs(:,1),:) - Vs(combs(:,2),:);
```

The above creates 3 random row vectors of dimension 5. So in your case, you may want to replace the creation of the random matrix with `Vs = [v1; v2; v3];` if your vectors are row vectors; or transpose the vectors using `Vs = [v1, v2, v3].';` if your data are column vectors.

Comment: This might be what OP is really after, I think! Use `cat` maybe to create `Vs` from `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc.?

Comment: @Divakar: Added the `cat`-details, so the OP will know how to make use of it.

Comment: Good job I also think this is what the OP is after d'oh! +1

Answer (score 1):

Using `bsxfun`:

```
clear
clc

%// Sample vectors.
v1 = [1 2];
v2 = [10 20];
v3 = [0 0];


Out = bsxfun(@minus,[v1 v2 v3], [v1 v2 v3].')

Out =

     0     1     9    19    -1    -1
    -1     0     8    18    -2    -2
    -9    -8     0    10   -10   -10
   -19   -18   -10     0   -20   -20
     1     2    10    20     0     0
     1     2    10    20     0     0
```

Reasoning: Each difference is computed starting from the 1st element of the 1st vector until the 2nd element of the last vector.

The 1st column contains all the differences for the 1st element of the 1st vector, i.e. (1 -1), (1-2), (1-10), (1 - 20), (1 - 0), (1 - 0).

Then 2nd column, same thing but this time with the 2: (2 - 1), (2 - 2), (2 - 10), and so on.

Sorry if my explanations are unclear haha I don't know the right terms in english. Please ask for more details.

Comment: Awesome and finally!! Just curious if the "pairing"  that OP talked about would be taken care of?

Comment: Oh shoot yes the pairing; I misunderstood the question! I think @knedlsepp is right on the spot.